# Who coined "times tables" and when?

Tags: phrase-origin, mathematics

I've always thought "times tables" to refer to multiplication tables was a British thing, but [Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table) it might be common in the US, too.

Is anything known about when the term was first used, who by, and whether it precedes the use of "multiplication tables"? I can't find anything in [the](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/times%20table) online [dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/multiplication-table) I've [looked](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/times-table) at.

Comment: "Times tables" is the main term I remember being used when I was in school (in the US), yeah.

Comment: The earliest book I've found so far that uses the term "times tables"  is *The Child's Instructor; or Learning Made Easy* (Ward, Lock & Co, London and New York, 1883).

Comment: It's nearly impossible to determine who coined a term like this. The best you can usually do is determine who first used it in print, but it had probably been used orally by teachers much longer.

Comment: Strike that. *John Heywood's Complete Series of Home Lesson Books*, Alfonzo Gardiner (London, 1882).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1864 is the year given for the first written usage of *times table* for the sense "multiplication table" in *OED*:

> **1864**     When this exercise can be readily done, pursue the same course with the three times table.
>               <sub>W. Easton, Complete Course Oral & Mental Arithm. 15</sub>

1863 is the year given for the first written usage without *table* for the same sense in *OED*:

> **1863**    I've said my ‘seven times’ over and over, Seven times one are seven.
>               <sub>J. Ingelow, *Poems* 160</sub>

However, *times* expressing multiplication goes back to Middle English and here is the first written usage by Chaucer from *OED*:

> ***c*1410**         The were nede of hennes, as I wene Ȝa, moo than seuen tymes seuentene.
>  **(*c*1390)**
>    <sub>G. Chaucer, *Nun's Priest's Tale* (Cambridge MS. Dd.4.24) (1902) l. 4644</sub>

<sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “time, n., sense II.19.d.ii”, July 2023. 
https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/5650505840</sub>

---

*Times table* for the obsolete original sense "a table of times, a timetable" is from 1844 per *OED*:

> **1844**    To Baden... Times table and fares not yet published.
>               <sub>F. Coghlan, *Hand-book Central Europe* 175/1</sub>

<sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “times table, n.”, July 2023. 
https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/7531546935</sub>

*Multiplication table* is from 1657 per *OED* so it precedes the usage of *times table*.

> **1657**    The multiplication Table thus ordered doth give the product of all the 9 digits 
>               placed orderly by every of the 9 digits.
>              <sub>W. Leybourn, *Arithmetick* iii. 244</sub>

<sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “multiplication table, n., sense 1”, July 2023. 
 https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/2828673392</sub>